# Найти середину отрезка Polyline

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть ломаная Polyline, известны координаты её начала и конца.

Стоит задача разделить ломаную на 2 равные части, каждую из которых сделать разным цветом.

Пробовал решить геометрически по Формуле вычисления координат середины отрезка, но при больших расстояниях вычисляемая точка отклоняется от изначального отрезка. [image: yandex map api]

Есть ли варианты решения?

Comment: "Пробовал решить геометрически" - ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Яндекс использует для карты проекцию Меркатора, поэтому всегда координаты центра надо считать, используя глобальные пиксельные координаты линии, а для отрисовки переводить обратно.

```
//Пикельные координаты линии:        
var linePixelGeo = myPolyline1.geometry.getPixelGeometry().getCoordinates(),
//Пиксельные координаты центра:
lineCenter = [(linePixelGeo[0][0]+linePixelGeo[1][0])/2,(linePixelGeo[0][1]+linePixelGeo[1][1])/2]
//Геокоординаты центра:
var geoLineCenter = myMap.options.get('projection').fromGlobalPixels(lineCenter, myMap.getZoom());
```

Не лучший пример, но результат виден: https://jsfiddle.net/Coroner1st/ze3jkwgb/